# MongoCollection.Update() using C# to update list<T>

Tags: c#, mongodb

[image]

I am using MongoVue application to show the data preview stored in "MongoDb".

In the attached image, the database name "Energy" has collection name "DataLog". In "DataLog", there are several rows. I am adding these row to the collection by reading it from a .CSV file.

Now sometimes the column name Pings has huge data [say array of 2000 items] for a single row due to which the exception occurs i.e if "MaxDocumentSize exceeds in 16MB"

Since the Pings array was huge which threw an exception and to avoid this, I removed the collection of Pings [i.e. entered blank collection] from row and tried to Insert, it went successful.

Now I want to update the Pings for the same entry, but in case the array is something like 2000 elements or above, then I wish to update it in group of 500 items [500 x 4 = 2000] in a loop.

Can anyone help me out.

** SAMPLE CODE **

```
   private void InsertData(Datalog xiDatalog)
    {
                List<Ping> tempPings = new List<Ping>();
                tempPings.AddRange(xiDatalog.Pings);
                xiDatalog.Pings.RemoveAll(x => x.RowId != 0);
                WriteConcernResult wc = mongoCollection.Insert(xiDatalog);
                counter++;


                var query = new QueryDocument("_id", xiDatalog.Id);
                MongoCursor<Datalog> cursor = mongoCollection.FindAs<Datalog>(query);

                foreach (Datalog data in cursor)
                {
                    AddPings(data, tempPings, mongoCollection);
                    break;
                }

    }

    private void AddPings(Datalog xiDatalog, List<Ping> xiPings, MongoCollection<Datalog> mongoCollection)
    {
        int groupCnt = 0;
        int insertCnt = 0;
        foreach (Ping px in xiPings)
        {
            xiDatalog.Pings.Add(px);
            groupCnt++;

            if (((int)(groupCnt / 500)) > insertCnt)
            {
                UpdateDataLog(xiDatalog.Id, xiDatalog.Pings, mongoCollection);
                insertCnt++;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool UpdateDataLog(BsonValue Id, List<Ping> tempPings, MongoCollection<Datalog> mongoCollection)
    {
        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            var query = new QueryDocument("_id", Id);
            var update = Update<Datalog>.Set(e => e.Pings, tempPings);
            mongoCollection.Update(query, update);
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }

        return success;
    }
```

Comment: The total document size cannot exceed 16mb. It seems like you're trying to insert the same amount of data, just in chunks? It would be more clear if you added the code you've tried.

Comment: Have you considered putting Pings in a different collection?

Comment: **Sample code added, please refer.**

Comment: @WiredPrairie: I think this MaxDocumentSize =16Mb is for adding data at a time. We can add any number of data in chunks. The problem is, I want to append the data in chunks to the Pings array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer :  Just modified the code to use Update.PushAll() instead of Update.Set()**

Please refer below code

```
private bool UpdateDataLog(BsonValue Id, List<Ping> tempPings, MongoCollection<Datalog> mongoCollection)
{
    bool success = false;

    try
    {
        var query = new QueryDocument("_id", Id);
        var update = Update<Datalog>.PushAll(e => e.Pings, tempPings);
        mongoCollection.Update(query, update);
        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = ex.Message;
    }

    return success;
}
```